# Recording PC's screen in the background?

Tags: windows-7, windows, screen-capture, screen-recorder

Is there a software like Camtasia Studio that records computer's screen but in the background so user won't notice?

I'm using Windows 7, putting it into sleep mode and would love this soft to start just after logging.

It would be nice if it could record at least 1-2 hours of work.

I'd love something known and legal like TeamViewer or Camtasia, I'm willing to install this software on a PC that I'm working on (for science! :)), and must be 100% sure this is not sending the data somewhere else/allowing someone to access my PC.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: By in the background, you mean secretly ? ;p

Comment: HackToHell, exactly. If there's a process in Process Manager - it's fine. If there's a icon in tray - it's still fine. I just don't want this software to disturb me while working.

Comment: A process would have to exist, otherwise if it didn't, then the applicationw wouldn't be running.

Answer (score 1):

Spector Log 2011 will allow you to record not only the screen, but audio and keylogging.

Answer (score 1):

If you looking for something that will take a snapshot every few seconds, rather than record a video of absolutely everything that happens. then TimeSpapper (from http://www.timesnapper.com/  ) may do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a little script with ffmpeg and put in to start with windows. I guess it is the most discrete, low use resource and more tweakble way to do this.